# Display three links when hovering on another link

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I want to display "W3" on my page. I want that when this "W3" is hovered, "West Acton", "North Acton" and "South Acton" are displayed in front of "W3" and all these are clickable links.

So I need to display 3 different links when I hover on a link.

For example:

```
.classname :hover : after {   
content : "url 1" "url 2" "url 3" ;
}
```

Comment: Can you also include some HTML code related to your question? It would be easier to understand what you need.

Comment: There's no such html but i will try to explain in detail. see i want to display "W3" on my page. i want that when this "W3" is hovered , West acton - North Acton and South Acton are displayed in front of "W3" and all these are clickable link. Thanks for your help.

Comment: like i can individually click on west Acton , South Acton and so on. we may need to use javascript. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces in the selector. `.classname :hover` means any hovered element *inside* an element with `classname`. You need `.classname:hover` if you want to address the classname'd element itself when hovered.

```css
.classname:hover::after {   
  content : "url 1"
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="classname">hover here </a>
```

Also, it's `::after` with two colons, since it's a pseudo-element. Although most browsers still support the old standard of one colon.
`:hover` is a pseudo-class, so it's good with one colon.

Edit: I see I seriously misread the question.
You want the ::after text to be a clickable link, or rather, three. CSS alone can't do that. You will need to put the three links in the html from the start, and then show them on hover.

Here you go.

```css
.container a {display:none}
.container:hover a {display:inline}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  hover here
  <a href="#">link 1</a> <a href="#">link 2</a> <a href="#">link 3</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. .its so simple.

Comment: OK. If this is the solution, can you mark it as such by clicking the check mark to the left, so the question no longer shows up in the list of unsolved ones.